# Need help on Socket Programming in Python (beginner)

Tags: python, sockets, command-line-arguments

I am learning socket programming and python. I need to create a client that sends a command to a server (list or get ).  The server then validates the command.  My client program can display "list" or "get" , but it doesn't show the error message when I enter other things.
Also, it only works one time; when I enter a different command after receiving a reply from the server, it gives me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fclient.py", line 49, in 
    client_socket.send(command)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')

I'm totally lost. What is the best way to get a command line input in the client program and send it to the server and ask the server to validate the command line parameter?  Can someone take a look and point me to the right direction? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Client.py

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys      #for exit

command = ' '
socksize = 1024

#return a socket descriptor which can be used in other socket related functions
#properties: address family: AF_INET (IP v4)
#properties: type: SOCK_STREAM (connection oriented TCP protocol)

try:
    #create an AF_INET, STREAM socket (TCP)
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:               #error handling
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ', Error message: ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit();

print 'Socket Created'

#Get the IP address of the remote host/url
#connect to IP on a certain 'port' using the connect
#host = 'flip3.engr.oregonstate.edu'
#port = 30021
#host = 'www.google.com'
#port = 80
host = ''       #symbolic name meaning the local host
port = 8888     #arbitrary non-privileged port

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Existing'
    sys.exit()
print 'IP address of ' + host + ' is ' + remote_ip

#Connect to remote server
client_socket.connect((remote_ip, port))
print 'Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip


#Send some data to remote server
while True:
    print 'Enter a command: list or get <filename>'
    command = raw_input()
    if command.strip() == 'quit':
        break
    client_socket.send(command)

    data = client_socket.recv(socksize)
    print data

#Close the socket
client_socket.close()
```

Server.py

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *

#HOST = 'flip3.engr.oregonstate.edu' #symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
#PORT = 30021
HOST = ''
PORT = 8888

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

try:
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))    #bind to a address(and port)
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#put the socket in listening mode
server_socket.listen(10)     #maximum 10 connections
print 'TCP Server Waiting for client on port 30021'

#wait to accept a connection - blocking call
client, addr = server_socket.accept()
#display client information
print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

#keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #Receiving from client
    data = client.recv(1024)

    if (data == 'list' or data == 'get'):
        reply = 'receive: ' + data
        client.send(reply)
        break;
    else:
        reply = 'wrong command'
        client.send(reply)

client.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you close your client socket *inside* your loop, closing it after receiving the reply to the first command. Move closing the socket out of the loop instead and introduce an exit condition to exit the loop:

```
#Connect to remote server
client_socket.connect((remote_ip, port))

print 'Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip

#Send some data to remote server
while True:
    print 'Enter a command: list or get <filename>'
    command = raw_input()
    if command.strip() == 'quit':
        break
    client_socket.send(command)

    data = client_socket.recv(socksize)
    print data

# Close the socket
client_socket.close()
```

You're doing something similar on the server side: You try to reopen the listening socket every iteration. Move this part out of the loop as well:

```
#wait to accept a connection - blocking call
client, addr = server_socket.accept()

#display client information
print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
```

The reason your command parsing doesn't work is because of this statement:

```
if (data == 'list' or 'get'):
```

What you meant to write here is

```
if (data == 'list' or data == 'get'):
```

The first expression will evaluate like this:

- Is `data == 'list'`?
- If yes, that sub-expression evaluates to `True` and is therefore what `a or b` will return.
- If not, the second operand to `or` is chosen, which is the string `'get'`.
- The result of that `or` expression will now be implicitely cast to boolean by the `if` statement:
- Case 1: `True` is already `True`
- Case 2: A non-empty string cast to boolean evaluates to `True` as well

So your `if` statement will always evaluate to `True`, that's why your command parsing didn't work.

To write

```
if (data == 'list' or data == 'get'):
```

in a nicer form, I would suggest to use

```
if (data.strip() in ('list'  'get')):
```

Lastly, you should wrap your socket code in a `try..finally` to make sure the sockets are always closed even if exceptions like a `KeyboardInterrupt` happen:

```
try:
    #keep talking with the client
    while 1:
        #Receiving from client
        data = client.recv(1024)

        if (data.strip() in ('list'  'get')):
            reply = 'receive: ' + data
            client.send(reply)
        else:
            reply = 'wrong command'
            client.send(reply)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Exiting gracefully."
finally:
    server_socket.close()
```

(The [`finally`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) clause gets executed under all circumstances - whether handled or undhandled exceptions happened, or not)

Comment: THANK U SOOO MUCH for the tips! It works now. =D Really appreciate it. Do you mind to answer one more question? If the user provides me a filename, e.g., get abc.txt. How can I read the text file name, search it within my directory and display the content of the text file? What topics should I look into (tutorial, example)?

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding your second question, look into [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split `'get abc.txt'` into `['get', 'abc.txt']`, the functions in the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module to build paths (`os.path.join`), make your path absolute (`os.path.abspath`) and checking for existence of a file (`os.path.isfile`). Look at [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to open the file. If you need help putting those together, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: U r awesome!!! =D Thanks again for your quick reply. I'll google the ones you told me.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you close `client_socket` in your while loop. After that, `client_socket.send()` will not work anymore.  There are at least two ways to fix this:

1. Move `client_socket.connect()` into your while loop also.
2. Get rid of `client_socket.close()`, and move `server_socket.accept()` above the while loop in Server.py.

There are more sophisticated options involving `select()` or other methods, but one of the two items above should get you by for now.